# Addition of every subset of two multiplied

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, math

I have an array with the elements {7,2,1} and the idea is to do 7 * 2 + 7 * 1 + 2 * 1 which is basically this algorithm:

```
for(int i=0;i<n-1;++i)
    for(int k=i+1;k<n;++k)
       sum += a[i] * a[k];
```

Where `a` is the array in which I have the numbers and `n` is the number of elements, I need a more efficient algorithm for doing this, and I have no clue how to do it, can someone give me a hand?

Thank you!

Comment: Make 1 pass , walk from the end to the front and form a `sum[]` of all the element "to the right".  2nd pass, Multiple `a[i] * sum[i]`.  O(n).

Comment: @chux can you make the bite of code? I don`t understand what you are trying to explain.

Comment: If you're willing to destroy the initial contents of the array, you can even perform @chux's approach in-place, in a single pass.

Comment: I am willing to destroy it  @JohnBollinger but I don`t undersand his approach.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do better in the general case. Time to do some math. Let's look at the 3-element version, we have:

```
ab + ac + bc
= 1/2 * (2ab + 2ac + 2bc)
= 1/2 * (2ab + 2ac + 2bc + a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - (a^2 + b^2 + c^2))
= 1/2 * ((a+b+c)^2 - (a^2 + b^2 + c^2))
```

That is:

```
int sum = 0;
int sum_sq = 0;
for (int i : arr) {
    sum += i;
    sum_sq += i*i;
}
int result = (sum*sum - sum_sq) / 2;
```

This is `O(n)` multiplications, instead of `O(n^2)`. This'll certainly be better than the naive implementation at some point. Whether or not it's better for just 3 elements is something I haven't timed.

Comment: chux and John Bollinger's solution have the same complexity but a small advantage: they do not have a larger intermediary result `sum * sum`.

Answer (score 6):

@chux's suggestion is essentially to redistribute operations:

a<sub>i</sub> * a<sub>i + 1</sub> + a<sub>i</sub> * a<sub>i + 2</sub> + ... + a<sub>i</sub> * a<sub>n</sub>

-->

a<sub>i</sub> * (a<sub>i + 1</sub> + ... + a<sub>n</sub>)

combined with the avoiding unnecessary recomputation of partial sums of the (a<sub>i + 1</sub> + ... + a<sub>n</sub>) terms by leveraging the fact that each differs from the next by the value of one element of the input array.

Here's a one-pass implementation with O(1) overhead:

```
int psum(size_t n, int array[n]) {
    int result = 0;
    int rsum = array[n - 1];

    for (int i = n - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
        result += array[i] * rsum;
        rsum += array[i];
    }

    return result;
}
```

The sum of all elements to the right of index `i` is maintained from iteration to iteration in variable `rsum`.  It's unnecessary to track its various values in an array, because we need each value only for one iteration of the loop.

This scales linearly with the number of elements in the input array.  You'll see that the number and type of operations is quite similar to @Barry's answer, but nothing analogous to his final step is required, which saves a few operations.

As @Barry observes in comments, the iteration can also be run in the other direction, in conjunction with tracking the left-hand partial sums intead of the right-hand ones.  That would diverge a bit more from @chux's description, but it relies on exactly the same principles.

Comment: You could just iterate forwards instead of backwards

Comment: @Barry, indeed so, by keeping a sum of the elements to the left instead of those to the right.

Comment: A small advantage of incrementing `result`, as in this answer, occurs when positive and negative elements are in the array.  Summing the squares  needs integer math  that is twice as wide as `int` and then some log2(n)  bits to perform the squares summation of `n` elements.  This approach can handle _some_ array sets that overflow the sum of squares approach.  IAC, overflow is neared should the max element-squared * `n` exceeds `INT_MAX`.

Answer (score 4):

Make 1 pass, walk from the end of `[a]` to the front and form a sum of all the elements "to the right".

2nd pass, Multiple `a[i] * sum[i]`.

O(n).

```
long sum0(int a[], int n) {
  long sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i)
    for (int k = i + 1; k < n; ++k)
      sum += a[i] * a[k];
  return sum;
}

long sum1(int a[], int n) {
  int long sums[n];
  sums[n - 1] = 0;
  for (int i = n - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
    sums[i] = a[i+1] + sums[i + 1];
  }

  long sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i)
    sum += a[i] * sums[i];
  return sum;
}

void test(int a[], int n) {
  long s0 = sum0(a, n);
  long s1 = sum1(a, n);
  if (s0 != s1) printf("%9ld %9ld\n", s0, s1);
}

void tests(int k) {
  while (k--) {
    int n = rand() % 10 + 2;
    int a[n + 1];
    for (int m = 0; m < n; m++)
      a[m] = rand() % 256;
    test(a, n);
  }
}

int main() {
  int a[3] = { 7, 2, 1 };
  printf("%d\n", sum1(a, 3));
  tests(1000000);
  puts("Done");
}
```

As it turns out the `sums[]` array is not needed either as the the running `sums` needs only 1 location.  This effectively makes this answers similar to others

```
long sum1(int a[], int n) {
  int long sums = 0;
  long sum = 0;
  for (int i = n - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
    sums = a[i+1] + sums;
    sum += a[i] * sums;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Comment: Setting aside the question of VLAs, `sum1()` simply doesn't give the right answer.

Comment: @barry, I disagree about "doesn't give the right answer" as the posted test code consistently gives the same answer as OP's O(n*n) approach.  Even with millions of runs.  Perhaps you can provide a counter example?

Comment: With `{7,2,1}`, `sums` would hold `{9,2,0}`, so `sum = 7*9+2*2 = 67`. The actual answer is 23.

Comment: I see the error in my test code.`long s0 = sum0(a,n);
  long s1 = sum0(a,n);`

Comment: Possible simplification: If instead of `sums = a[i+1] + sums;` in the loop before `sum += a[i] * sums;` you put `sums += a[i]` after, you can run the loop as `for (size_t i = n; i-- > 0;)` for any size arrays, including empty.

Comment: @chqrlie Agreed, I like your `size_t` index type  and the simplified code.

Comment: @chux: we seem to be on the same tune most of the time... where are you based?

Comment: @chqrlie west about 6900 km.

Comment: @chux: Really? Well, I haven't been in ND for 33.5 years ;-)

Answer (score 4):

We have (a + b + c + ...)<sup>2</sup> = (a<sup>2</sup> + b<sup>2</sup> + c<sup>2</sup> + ...) + 2(ab + bc + ca + ...)

You want the sum S = ab + bc + ca + ..., which has O(n<sup>2</sup>) pairs (using 2 nested loops)

You can do 2 separated loops, one calculates P = a<sup>2</sup> + b<sup>2</sup> + c<sup>2</sup> + ... in O(n) time, and another calculates Q = (a + b + c + ...)<sup>2</sup> also in O(n) time. Then take S = (Q - P) / 2.